# Why can't my blog post be displayed in pythonanywhere.com

Tags: django

I am a beginner of Django, just followed the tutorial to create a blog of my own, but the posts of my blog cannot be displayed normally in pythonanywhere.com
These are my files:
**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kington's blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="page-header">
          <div class="container">
              <h1><a href="/">Kington's Blog</a></h1>
          </div>
        </header>
        <main class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

**post_list.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="post">
            <time class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </time>
            <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <article class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <time class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </time>
        {% endif %}
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404


# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

At first I thought it was my database that wasn't updated, then I googled and tried updating pythonanywhere's database, but that didn't help.
In the end, I deleted all the files on the website except the default files, then downloaded my code from github again, and rebuilt a personal website through pythonanywhere.com again, which can display my head title.
But posts still can't be displayed.

Comment: Could you give more details about what you mean when you say that the posts can't be displayed?  Do you get an empty page, an error message, or something else?

Comment: @Giles Thomas Sorry It's my fault I didn't make it clear.
the posts can display normally on 127.0.0.1:8000, but it couldn't work on the website which built by pythonanywhere
I can confirm that the code on pythonanywhere.com is the same as my local code
There is one more thing I forgot to say, that is the header can display but the body not

Comment: Could you share url of the blog?

Comment: If you have not transfered the database on your local machine to PythonAnywhere, then the contents of the database will not be available on PythonAnywhere